Update CodeLens titles by timer
I have a project using Monaco-editor. We use it for ST language and we need to realize realtime displaying values for variables. For this feature I want to use CodeLens to display value and then when user click on this CodeLens editor opens window to set variable value.
Question: CodeLens title sets ones, how can I update title by using timer
Code example:
monaco.languages.registerCodeLensProvider(langName, {
      provideCodeLenses: async function (model, token) {
            /*code*/
            codeLenses.push({
              range: {
                startLineNumber: startPos.lineNumber,
                startColumn: startPos.column,
                endLineNumber: endPos.lineNumber,
                endColumn: endPos.column,
              },
              command: {
                id: 'showVariableValue',
                title: `${variable}: ${value}`,
              })
          }
        }

        return { lenses: codeLenses, dispose: () => { } };
      },
    });

setInterval(() => {
      call update CodeLenses
    }, 1000);


I've already tried this solution suggested by chatGPT, but it didn't work for me.
    setInterval(() => {
      editor.layout(); // 1
      monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider(langName, customMonarchSyntax); // 2
    }, 1000);


I found a solution, but it's terrible.
function UpdateValuesFromHTML() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.codelens-decoration > a').forEach(el => {
    let variable = el.text.split(': ')[0];
    el.text = variable + ": " + getRandomMoonitoringValue();
  })
}

